# Is it ok to delete some Google cloud projects?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I am sorry if this is something too simple, but I could not find a quide that would provide me with answers for question as profound as this.

During the past years I have built many Wordpress sites. I have never intentionally or knowingly used Cloud Platform, but still some of the websites are listed as a projects under Google Cloud (Manage resources -page).

**Question 1:** Why are these websites listed there as a projects (seemingly all by their own, I have not created these projects)? Why some of the websites that I have built are not listed? I have used Google Analytics and Google Search Console but I can't find a pattern to figure out why only some sites appear in Google Cloud. Also I have once or twice used Maps API but it does not correspond with the abount of projects.

**Question 2:** Since I do not actively work with these projects, is it ok to delete these projects listed in Google Cloud? How will it affect to the websites, I'd assume there is no effect If I actively have not built the projects under Cloud in the first place? The ownership/administration of some of the sites have changed already and I have nothing to do with them.

Thank you very much!

I already deleted some of the projects as a test.

Answer (score 2):

Projects are a top-level concept in GCP.  So if you delete a Project, you will delete all resources belonging to the Project, including Cloud Storage buckets, if you are hosting a static site.